# Kimono Regular Expressions for pagination

Tags: regex, pagination, kimono

I'm trying to use kimono to paginate a URL.
I don't like to ask for help, but this time I really tried for myself without effort.  I tried to read about Regular expressions, and also I searched in forums with no effort.
I wrote to the Kimono support, but they didn't answered my mails asking for the correct formula.

The specific URL is  http://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/category/cat690251/Zapatos-Mujer?No=0&Nrpp=40

By default, the pagination method provided by Kimono doesn't work for this.
This page has numbers from 1 to 8 (and a symbol '>' which cannot be selected).

So. I click in 'pagination' but when I select a number, lets say the '8' the Kimono will just paginate the EIGHT page..

which seems logical when I check in the advanced pagination menu, because the formula used is:   /^()(8)()$/

So, my attemps where directed towards provide the formula with a range, something like:

/^()(2-8)()$/ but it doesn't work

Kimono won't allow me to use just (2-8)  because they force the user to imput a formula with this fixed format:     /()()()/

which expression should I try ?

I tried doubleclicking the '>' symbol and it seems to work, but from three times, it throws error in 2.

Some error codes are:
E5: Kimono could not create an API
E10: No elements found for all selectors
E20: Pagination Error: Selector not found

The regular expression when I click '>' is: /(\t\t\t)([^]*?)(\t\n\t)/

Nor doubleclicking the numers does work:  /^()([^]*?)()$/

Please help.
Please excuse my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the 'next page link' cannot be selected by clicking (because it is an image, rather than text). In order to make pagination work on this page, you'll need to manually enter the selector using 'advanced mode' instead of relying on the click.

To do this:

1. Set up your API with all the desired data properties
2. Click the blue pagination button in the toolbar
3. Go to the data model view
4. Click 'Advanced'
5. Scroll down to the 'Pagination' property
6. Enter `div#bul-flecha-derecha > a#pre-page` as your selector
7. Leave the default regular expression
8. Click submit to save the changes
9. Click Done and name and create your API